# How do I install legacy drivers for an HD4250 on 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, installation, drivers, ati, fglrx

I seen some instructions about workarounds for 12.10, but I don't want to risk breaking my system which is something that already happened when I installed the regular FGLRX drivers.

Answer (score 1):

ati Hd 2xxx-4xxx series not supported in 12.10 with 12.9 catalyst so check this link how to install it

- http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/10/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-legacy.html

Comment: Thanks for the help but as I said I'm in 12.04, not 12.10. I did find a guide for 12.10 that afaik works but I dont want to risk breaking my install

Comment: you can activate driver search 'drivers' in dash and activate it. Or install it in synaptic search for fglrx. Or download from ati in drivers support and make it executable in file properties run and follow the instructions.